# Android 6.0 mtp device not showing in Nautilus

Tags: usb, nautilus, android, 16.10, mtp

My Android devices - Xioami Mi 5s, Google Nexus 4 running Android 6.0.1 and Google Nexus 7 LTE running Android 4.4.2 - are not accessible from Nautilus 3.20 in Ubuntu 16.10. At least two of them worked in 15.10 before I upgraded to Yakkety Yak.

Adb can access the devices.

libmtp9, libmtp-common, libmtp-runtime are installed and I recently installed:

- mtp-tools
- go-mtpfs
- mtpfs

/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules contains entries for the devices

mtp-connect lists

> libmtp version: 1.1.12
>
> Device 0 (VID=18d1 and PID=4ee2) is a Google Inc (for LG
>   Electronics/Samsung) Nexus 4/5/7/10 (MTP+ADB). Device 1 (VID=2717 and
>   PID=ff48) is a Xiaomi Mi-2s (MTP). Android device detected, assigning
>   default bug flags

mtp-detect shows the devices are detected but reports the error:

> Error 1: Get Storage information failed.

lsusb doesn't list the Xiaomi, but it lists the Google devices:

> Bus 001 Device 017: ID 18d1:d002 Google Inc. 
>   Bus 001 Device 014: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug)

/run/user/1000/gvfs which should contain the mount points for mtp devices is empty.

None of them are listed in Nautilus. Can anyone suggest how to get this working again?

Comment: Do you remember to change the phone(s) from "Charge" to "Transfer files" or some other sensible option on the phone ?

Comment: Yes - the Android 6 ones are on: Transfer Files (MTP) mode

Answer (score 0):

Check your device connectivity by running `mtp-detect`.

If you've got the following error:

> error returned by libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device

You need to activate MTP file transfer on your Android device. For example:

1. [Activate *Developer Settings*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/33496/110425) by tapping 7 times *Build number* in About phone.
2. Enable *File transfer* in *USB configuration* found in *Developer options*.

See: [How can I access media on my OnePlus 5 with a Ubuntu OS?](https://superuser.com/q/1270307/87805)