# Android devices stopped showing up in Nautilus (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, mtp

When I connect my Android cellphone to my home PC it does not show up in Nautilus - a nice cellphone icon labeled Android should show up on the sidebar but only additional CD-ROM shows up. No success with a different cellphone and a camera. On My home PC the *gmpt* can access both the cellphone internal and additional memories but Nautilus cannot do that anymore.

When I connect the phone to my office lapton then it shows up in Nautilus - both Android and CD-ROM shows up. It works perfectly.

Both computers: the same Ubuntu version, the same software installed, the same configurations. Maybe I've messed up something on my home PC while learning Ubuntu?

On my home PC the *mtp-detect* returns:

```
libmtp version: 1.1.13
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=0b05 and PID=5f02) is a Asus Zenfone 2 ZE550ML (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Asus: Zenfone 2 ZE550ML (MTP) (0b05:5f02) @ bus 1, dev 18
Attempting to connect device(s)
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
```

and a lot of `USB low-level` info.

*lsusb* returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0b05:5f02 ASUSTek Computer, Inc.
```

*ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/018* returns:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 189, 17 maj 28 20:46 /dev/bus/usb/001/018
```

On my office laptop the *mtp-detect* returns:

```
libmtp version: 1.1.13
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=0b05 and PID=5f02) is a Asus Zenfone 2 ZE550ML (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Asus: Zenfone 2 ZE550ML (MTP) (0b05:5f02) @ bus 1, dev 24
Attempting to connect device(s)
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

Similar questions, but not helpful: [Ubuntu 18.04 does not connect to Android smartphone](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034919/830248), [Samsung USB not showing in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031007/830248), [Android 6.0 mtp device not showing in Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/q/862988/830248).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to reinstall Nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

I've found the results of the installation command especially interesting:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gvfs-backends
(...)
Selecting previously unselected package gvfs-backends.
(...)
Setting up gvfs-backends (1.36.1-0ubuntu1) ...
```

It is possible I've removed gvfs-backends unwittingly while playing around with network and SMB.

Answer (score 0):

> error returned by libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: Unable to initialize device

Most likely you need to activate MTP file transfer on your Android device by the following steps:

1. [Activate *Developer Settings*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/33496/110425) by tapping 7 times *Build number* in About phone.
2. Enable *File transfer* in *USB configuration* found in *Developer options*.

See: [How can I access media on my OnePlus 5 with a Ubuntu OS?](https://superuser.com/q/1270307/87805)