# Ubuntu 20 LTS MTP device only showing up right after reboot

Tags: 20.04, usb, nautilus, android, mtp

I'm using ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and no MTP devices are showing up in files.
I'm trying to access the files on my phone and tablet (both android) but neither shows up when I connect them over USB and enable data transfer.
`mtp-detect` does detect both devices but I need to run it as root to see all information.

**However**, Just after I reboot the computer the MTP devices are detected correctly and shown in file manager BUT when I disconnect the MTP device and try to connect it or any other mtp device it won't show up again.

Things I tried:

- I [reinstalled nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041657/1569853)
- My system is up to date
- I reinstalled `mtp-tools`

Comment: please with usb devices connected `lsusb` [edit] your question for output. maybe it needs an udev rule

Comment: Please be precise with details. 20 is a different system/product to 20.04; Ubuntu has used the year format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) to highlight *snap* only products that have 10 years of supported life since 2016; so 20 != 20.04.  In your title you indicate you're using a *snap* only 20 server product, but later mention a *deb* based 20.04??